# Inequality proof on polynomials and exponential

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, exponential-function

I want to prove the following :

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R^n}$ and $C,a,b \in \mathbb{R}^+$ with $a<b$ then $\exists C'$ s.t. $\forall t \geq0$ :
>
> $$||f(t)|| \leq C (1+t)^{n-1}e^{-bt} \implies ||f(t)|| \leq C'e^{-at}.$$

I have proven that :

1. $C (1+t)^{n-1}e^{-bt}$ vanishes at infinity for all n,
2. Then $C (1+t)^{n-1}e^{-bt}$ is bounded (on $\mathbb{R}^+$),
3. $\forall m, C (1+t)^{n-1}e^{-bt}=o_{t \to \infty}(t^m)$.

Can I deduce the result from this ?
Thank you.

---

**Edit**

I think I have answered myself, I went the wrong way.

The following quantity :
$$\dfrac {C (1+t)^{n-1}e^{-bt}}{e^{-at}}=C (1+t)^{n-1}e^{-(b-a)t}$$
is bounded (on $\mathbb{R}^+$) by a certain quantity $M$ (because it vanishes at infinity and is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^+$).

Then it follows immediately, $\forall t>0$ :
$$||f(t)|| \leq C (1+t)^{n-1}e^{-bt} \leq Me^{-at}.$$

Is it ok ?